# 500 Error - server can’t handle the request on few devices

Tags: php, browser, browser-cache

I have a PHP website with following structure.

```
/Root/
 - Folder A
 - Folder B
    - Folder BA
    - Folder BB
 - Folder C
 - Folder D
```

Problem is, All root files and all subfolders pages working ok on maximum all laptops and mobile devices.

But today, two members of my website reported that they can not access Folder B and Folder C **on laptop**. Rest Root and Folder A And Folder D are working normally.

On visiting Folder B And Folder C, **they are seeing 500 Error -  server can’t handle the request** (for all links in these folders. Rest all other members can access normally. Even these two members can access the site from their mobiles

I checked htaccess in the root, there are no htaccess files in subfolders.

I checked their laptops via TeamViewer, all settings are ok.

What can be issues and solutions?

Comment: Check what the error log has to say first of all.

Comment: @CBroe No errors in error log...

Comment: @CBroe I think it is related to those members Browser settings / IP4 network settings / DNS settings... I already tried cache, cookies clear etc via TemViewer..

Comment: _“No errors in error log”_ - a 500 message on the front end, without _anything_ about it logged in the server’s error log - that is very unlikely.

Comment: @CBroe Yes.... I also surprised... and so I think it is related to those members Browser settings / IP4 network settings / DNS settings... But unable to sort it out... :(

Comment: I don’t see how _any_ of the things you mention should be relevant here, if the users don’t have problems reaching the site per se, but it only occurs with specific folders.

Comment: @DrManishLataa-ManoharJoshi No, it's not related to browser settings.  Make sure you enable logging on your server so you can see what's actually happening.

Comment: @Brad But other members are accessing those folders normally and even these two members are also able to access those folders from their mobile phones. But seeing error on laptop only..

Comment: @DrManishLataa-ManoharJoshi Yeah, well, **what do your logs say**?  Who knows what you're doing server-side... we certainly don't, you didn't post any code or anything.  There is probably a cookie or session data or something messing things up.